Angular 18 with SSR: Setting optimization to true ignores library loaded inside scripts
My Angular 18 application runs smoothly with SSR in development mode. However, when I switch to production mode with optimization set to true, the application fails to locate the 'igv.js' file, even though it is already included in the scripts section of the angular.json file.
Configurations section:
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "namedChunks": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "outputHashing": "all"
    },
    "development": {
      "optimization": false,
      "extractLicenses": false,
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  },

Scripts section:
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
      "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js",
      "igv.js"
    ],

This is how I am calling the IGV module. Since I am using SSR, I have to call the file on the client-side.
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      import('igv').then(igvModule => {
        const igv = igvModule.default;
        if (igv && typeof igv.createBrowser === 'function') {
          this.igvModule = igv;
        } else {
          console.error('igv.createBrowser is not a function');
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading igv module:', error);
      });
    }
  }

Any suggestion on what could be missing?

Could you try importing igv directly using the below import and start using it on your components?
import igv from '../node_modules/igv/dist/igv.esm.js';

Related github issue

With optimisation set to true, it still doesn't work

@Kim You have to use this import in your code, else it will get removed by tree shaking, that is what I think is wrong.

Hi @naren, I have updated my question. I am calling the file on the client-side

@Kim Using this import, could you replace this.igvModule with just igv it should work! There is no need for the import code

Yes, it works now!! I have updated my import with the relative file path :)
